# Query with two complementary values for each row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a subquery in a very large query that has to do the following

with an array of couples of clusters

> array(array(c1, c2), array(c3, c4), array(c5, c6), array(c7, c8))

where for example c1 and c2 are complementary,  c3 and c4 as well ..etc .
and i have a table state :

```
id_state cluster   successfull   failed  success_ratio   
  1        c1           4            0       100%  
  2        c2           1            9       10%   
  3        c3           0            4        0%         
  4        c4           1            1        50%
```

note that which cluster is coupled with the another is determined using the array above.

and the final output that i would like to have :

```
   cluster  successfull success_ratio                        
       c1         4        100%    (for the first pair)
       c4         1        50%      (for the second)
```

is there a way to do a query that gets the success_ratio of all the data by taking only 
from each couple the one with the success_ratio > 50% and only if both have success_ratio < 50% then just take the first one.

Is this even achievable using only a mysql query (i can't use query result since i want it as a subquery of another large query) ?

even if you can just suggest a starting point for a way to do it that would be appreciated.

Comment: What if both have success rations greater than 50%?

Comment: Can you give an example of your desired input and output?

Comment: @gordon-linoff then i should just take the first success ratio

Comment: @alex-w just added an edit for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want the maximum success ratio for each pair.

```
select s.grp, max(success_ratio)
from state s join
     (select 'c1' as cluster, 1 as grp union all
      select 'c2', 1 union all
      select 'c3', 2 union all
      select 'c4', 2 union all
      select 'c5', 3 union all
      select 'c6', 3 union all
      select 'c7', 4 union all
      select 'c8', 4
     ) grps
     on s.cluster = grps.cluster
group by s.grp;
```

If you actually want the rows with the best success, then use a subquery:

```
select s.*
from (select s.grp,
      substring_index(group_concat(cluster order by success_ratio desc), ',', 1) as bestcluster
      from state s join
           (select 'c1' as cluster, 1 as grp union all
            select 'c2', 1 union all
            select 'c3', 2 union all
            select 'c4', 2 union all
            select 'c5', 3 union all
            select 'c6', 3 union all
            select 'c7', 4 union all
            select 'c8', 4
           ) grps
           on s.cluster = grps.cluster
      group by s.grp
     ) b join
     state s
     on s.cluster = b.cluster
```

Comment: thanks @gordon-linoff, realy helpful answer, pointed me to the right direction